# is there any way to invert image for IE11

Tags: css

I used css for invert the image for IE11 but it is not working

```
.five {
-webkit-filter: invert(90%);
-moz-filter: invert(90%);
-o-filter: invert(90%);
-ms-filter: invert(90%);
filter: invert(90%);
}
```

Comment: The css property invert is not supported by IE11. A quick way to check this is to use: https://caniuse.com/#search=invert

Comment: in IE11 that feture is not supported. you can try Edge.